# clear the graphics  when mouse is rolledout from a canvas

Tags: flex4

I have created a tilelist and each tile of tile list is a canvas where graphics is drawn on rollover. When mouse is rolled out from that particular canvas the graphics drawn has to be removed. So I am doing **graphics.clear** but not able to remove the graphics.

Code

```
protected function canvas1_updateCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {           
                var allowHighLight:Boolean = QzGridImpl(this.owner).m_bEnableHighLight;
                if(!allowHighLight)
                    return;
                var highLighted:Boolean = TileList(this.owner).isItemHighlighted(this.data);
                if(highLighted)
                {
                    high = true;
                    DrawBackgroundImage(QzGridImpl(this.owner).m_strBackgroundImage as String);


                }
//when highlighted becomes false the below part is called
                else
                {

                    if(high)
                    {



                        this.graphics.endFill();//and cleanly im observing that endfill and clear is getting called and they are able to clear graphics when mouse is rolled out slowly but not able to clear when mouse is rolled out fast.

                        trace("endfill");
                        this.graphics.clear();
                        trace("clear");



                    }
                }


private function DrawBackgroundImage(n_strBackImg:String):void
{

//code for drawing the background image
}
```

and cleanly I am observing that endfill and clear is getting called and they are able to clear graphics when mouse is rolled out slowly but not able to clear when mouse is rolled out fast.

What need to be done to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom ItemRenderer for the TileList, and apply the image effect when the rollover is triggered in the itemRenderer (by adding a rollOver listener to the renderer). That might work - and is probably a neater way of doing it too.